# rxjs infinite loop when adding to ngrx store

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

```
// component.html
<button (click)="reRoute(1)">Select</button>

// component.ts
reRoute(id: any) {
  this.store.select(fromStore.getBasketEntities).subscribe(data => {
     const url = id + '_' + Object.keys(data).length; // contruct new url
     this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.AddItem(id)); // EDIT: add item to store

     // this.router.navigate(['quote/details/' + url], {
     //   queryParams: { type: 'product' }
     // });
  });
}
```

I have the above which causes the console to go into an infinite loop of outputting the `url` in `1_0`, then `1_1`, `1_2` and so on. Multiple items are being added to my store on ‘one’ single click of the button..

What I’m trying to do is add an item on every click but get the number of the items in my store each time. Initially 0 and append this to the item in the store. The first item will have an index of `1_0`. The next time I click the button, another item will be added with an index of `1_1` and so on.

Any help much appreciated. Seams so straight forward but this has kept me busy for hours…

**EDIT**: I change the `url` to `id`. Same issue happens. I want to route to the added item straight after the click - so for the first item ever added the route would be `/details/1_0/`. This route then has logic to retrieve the item from the store and display it's details.

Just thought I'd add that to complete the overall picture of what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks

**EDIT_2:** I moved the `dispatch` outside of the subscribe which solves the continues adding of the item to the store but I'm still getting 2 x console logs on every button click `4_0` and then `4_1` the first time the button is clicked. I'm wondering now how I will handle the `router.navigation`

```
reRoute(id: any) {
    this.store.select(fromStore.getBasketEntities).subscribe(data => {
        const url = id + '_' + Object.keys(data).length; // contruct new url
        console.log(url); // debug
        // this.router.navigate(['quote/details/' + url], {
        //   queryParams: { type: 'product' }
        // });
    });
   this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.AddItem(id)); // add item to store
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're subscribing on a slice of the store state with

```
this.store.select(fromStore.getBasketEntities)
```

This means every time the basket entities changes, the function inside `subscribe` is getting executed. I'm assuming the `AddItem` action does modify this slice of the store store, meaning it will re-trigger the the `select` and so on.

You should only dispatch the `AddItem` action in the click event with the `id` as payload. Inside the reducer function you can calculate the `url`.

```
reRoute(id: any) {
  this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.AddItem(id));
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I added that logic within the reducer and only pass `id` now but I've added a bit more to explain where I need `url` - the same happens in the console still.

Comment: You're still dispatching your action inside the select subscription, creating the 'infinite loop'. See my answer on how it should be.

Comment: Thanks - I've moved it outside of the subscription but I need to set the router.navigation - or would that happen in the reducer also...?

Comment: No your reducer doesn't know anything from the Angular router. You could use ngrx/effects to navigate - https://blog.angularindepth.com/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this-e0b2bd9da165